# Ubuntu & Win10 dual boot - shared data partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10, data-corruption

I have an ASUS notebook dual boot Win10 and Ubuntu 16.04. I also set up a data partition formated as FAT32, so that both systems can use it.

I first worked in Windows and saved some of my files in the shared partition. Then I switched to Ubuntu and also saved considerable amount of work in the shared data partition. I could see and use all files that I previously saved in Windows. Then few days later I went back to Windows, but I could only see the files I previously created in Windows in the shared partition, no files saved in Ubuntu were there. When I logged back in Ubuntu and opened the data partition, I could only see the few days old files created originally in Windows, but none of my files that I saved when working in Ubuntu!

Is there a way to recover them? And what happened here - I was only saving files from Windows and Ubuntu to a shared partition, but when I went back to Windows, it looks like it restored that partition to as it was when I was last logged into Windows, removing all Ubuntu created files! Help!

Comment: Had you disabled Windows fast boot option? Did you completely shut down Windows (i.e. not hibernate) before booting Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, the fast boot option in Windows is disabled and Windows was properly shut down.